# Playing with placeholder in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, placeholder, angularjs-interpolate

Is there like a kind of ng-placeholder or something similar ?

I want to put a default placeholder which is `Risk`, that is for an input which is a calculation input, sometimes the calculation last 2 seconds, so I want to remove that `Risk` placeholder and put a loader/spinner there. This is how I have it

```
    <div>

      <div>
        <span ng-show="betLoader"><div class="spinner"></div></span>
        <div ng-show="!betLoader">Win</div>
      </div>

      <input placeholder="Risk"
             ng-model="parlayData.win">
    </div>
```

I have there a `$scope` variable `betLoader`, when it is `true` the loader/spinner appears, when it is false, `div` with the word **Win** appears. I want to do the same but not there, I want to do it in the input with the placeholder **Risk**, when `betLoader` is true, then hide the **Risk** word.

What are your suggestions ?

**EDIT**

take into account that the spinner is in a `div` with the class `spinner`. So, I need to put that spinner within the input.

Comment: There's not an `ng-placeholder`, but there's a `placeholder="{{bindHere}}"`...

Comment: OK, but how I do that ? I want to put ```Risk``` word as a default placeholder, so, when betLoader is false, how risk come up ? @mypal125

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could directly use interpolation `{{}}` directive directly in placeholder attribute.

**Markup**

```
<input placeholder="{{betLoader ? 'Risk': ''}}" ng-model="parlayData.win">
```

**Update**

To update spinner content you could use `ng-bind-html` there.

**Html**

```
  <div>
    <div ng-bind-html="betLoader ? '<span class="spinner"></span>': 'Win'"><div class="spinner"></div></span>
    <div ng-show="!betLoader">Win</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, but look at this line: ```<span ng-show="betLoader"><div class="spinner"></div></span>``` what I need to put into that placeholder is something like the spinner class. That class is the one which contains the spinner.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer you want to conditionally check add `spinner` div and `Win` text then you could simply use `ng-bind-html` in that case. Look at my edit..

Answer (score 2):

There is no builtin `ng-placeholder` directive, you can use regular `placeholder` with `{{scopeParam}}` or just implement the `ng-directive`

**The advantage** of implementing the `ng-placeholder` is that if it takes time for your page to load, you wont see plain `{{scopeParam}}` as the placeholder of your input

The implementation is very simple:

```js
angular.module('ph', [])
//directive starts here
  .directive('ngPlaceholder', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.attr("placeholder",attrs.ngPlaceholder);
      }
    };
  })
//directive ends here

  .controller("phCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.ph="The placeholder"
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ph" ng-controller="phCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-placeholder="{{ph}}" />
</div>
```